# Rmarkdown officedown block_landscape no page number

Tags: r, r-markdown, officedown

I use officedown because I want to take advantage of the ability to `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_START--->` and `<!---BLOCK_LANDSCAPE_STOP--->`.
When I used the Officedown template (the advanced Word document) page numbers were only displayed after the landscape section. When I deleted the landscape section, all pages were numbered.
I want to have page numbers throughout the document, i.e. before landscape, in landscape and after landscape.
Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please make clear what your desired outcome is. Is it to have the landscape section numbered as well?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, when using a mix of landscape callouts listed by the OP with a YAML `reference_docx`, the reference headers do not carry over between block callouts. Instead they only appear after the final one concludes. The desired outcome is to have a mix of landscape and portrait pages that maintain the reference doc template header.